# How to navigate from fragment in one activity to fragment in another activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I want to add back navigation to toolbar. I need to get from a fragment in an activity to a specific fragment in another activity.

It looks a little like this, where every orange line means navigating to a new activity or fragment:

[image]

How do I move from fragment B to fragment A from OtherActivity?

Comment: Do fragments A and B take up whole screen in their activities? And are they only fragments that are shown in these activities?

Comment: Have you tried code?

Comment: Have you tried events or interface/

Comment: Fragment A takes up the whole screen in its activity but fragment B does not. I am going to add a picture of the activities and the fragments for you to see. @Marat

Comment: @Eenvincible how would the interface option work.

Comment: Let me try to answer this

Comment: Please check out my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider these steps:

From `Activity` 1 holding `Fragment` A , you want to directly load `Fragment` B in `Activity` 2.

Now, I am thinking first, then you press a button in `Fragment A`, you can directly go to `Activity B`.

Then it means, you can simply load `Fragment B` as soon as you arrive in `Activity` 2.

Since you are dealing with back navigation (I believe you mean the `upNavigation`?), you can override the following:

But watch clearly, because if you need to load an exact fragment in Activity 2, you need to know somehow:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("frag", "fragmentB");
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

As you can see, when you click the back arrow on the toolbar, we pass a value through our intent to identity which fragment we want to load.

Next, in your `Activity2`, simply get the `intent extra` and do a switch or an `if statement`:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
  super.onResume();

  Intent intent = getIntent();

  String frag = intent.getExtras().getString("frag");

  switch(frag){

    case "fragmentB":
       //here you can set Fragment B to your activity as usual;
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_body, new FragmentB()).commit();
       break;
  }
}
```

From here, you should have your Fragment B showing in Activity 2.

Now you can handle the same thing while inside Activity 2 to decide where to go when a user clicks the back home arrow!

I hope this helps you get an idea.

Note: I thought about the interface approach and realized it is not necessary since this can be done easily with this approach!

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference. @Eenvincible. Btw I really like your apps, I had a look at them on the play store!

Comment: Hey thanks Tom; let me help you with this; you see, you have to make sure the intent is not null first inside onResume; we can chat if you need more help

Comment: By the way, if you are coming into Activity 2 from another location, you have to pass the extra to the intent as well - that way, won't be null

Comment: I need more help can we chat? @Eenvincible

Comment: Yeah let us move this to chat please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118031/discussion-between-eenvincible-and-tom-finet).

Answer (score 0):

To navigate from one Activity to another Activity's Fragment, with Kotlin version 1.4.0 and, for example, calling a click listener on a button it works so:

```
 binding.yourButton.setOnClickListener {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.yourLayout, NameOfYourFragment()).commit()
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this code to change your fragment

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_body, new FragmentC()).commit();
```

and to show navigation on custom toolbar add

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
   ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```